# Read exactly N bytes from serial port

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, serial-port

How do I read exactly `N` bytes from serial port? I need my thread to block until at least `N` bytes is available on port or a preset timout has expired. Both timout value and `N` should be variable during runtime.

Note: On Linux using C/C++ with or without boost.

Comment: A loop is the obvious solution.

Comment: I would prefer a magic system call to block my thread until data is available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as hinted at by Hans, comms channels that communicate only byte streams do not, as a rule, have any magic calls to block up the bytes into protocol units - you have to do it yourself.  It's not that difficult.

Similarly timeouts.  COM port drivers commonly have a timeout that fires when no bytes have been received for some interval, but that cannot time out any sort of protocol unit more complex than that one byte.  If I need to do something like that, I typically use one thread that received bytes and assembles protocol unit objects until they are complete and sanity-checked, then pushes them to a P-C queue.  Another thread waits on the queue with a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

There is `VMIN` attribute in termios for that purpose. It can be used for preventing `read()` to return when there are not enough bytes available.

Example:

```
tcgetattr( fd, &termiosv );

termiosv.c_cc[VMIN]  = N;
termiosv.c_cc[VTIME] = 20;

tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &termiosv );
```

[More about VMIN](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/termios-vmin-vtime.html).

Note:
It does effect to `select()`: Select indicates fd readability when there are only 1 byte available and VMIN > 1.

Comment: Is this possible to change VMIN at runtime?

Comment: Yes, in the example it is changed runtime (not compile time) for open file descriptor of a serial device. I have used it only right after serial port opening during initialization of port. So I don't know does it flush buffers or cause other side effects.